# I am unable to restore my whatsapp chats while switching to new phone

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore

I switched to a new phone. I copied whatsapp folders- Database and media to the laptop. The database file has correct name as suggested by whatsapp faq- msgstore.db.crypt and it is version 12 only. But when i install whatsapp it does not take that local backup and asks to check google drive. I don't have backup on google drive.
Later i tried new idea- I disconnected internet after verification of mobile number and yes so it prompted - >backup found- Restore> i tapped restore, but still my chats didn't backedup, the restore processing also did not took lace, i turned on internet after tapping restore. what's the matter? please help. I have some really important stuff. You all are tech enthusiast here. i hope you can help me in this minor problem. I have local Backup, i have mobile, i have application. What else is needed??

Comment: Please try this step. Its just a test method, I hope this may work. Remove old copied folders from device uninstall whatsapp and remove whatsapp folder(keep it on another storage/USB etc ).  Install whatsap app on new device. after completing verification and all, it will create whtasapp folder. then copy old folders to exact folders that match with them. That means keep databases files on database folder. Then force stop whatsapp. clear all data. repeat initial processes and on complete I think you can see old items on your new device.

Comment: https://www.fonepaw.com/solution/transfer-whatsapp-messages-android-to-android.html, https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-my-old-WhatsApp-chat-in-my-new-phone

Comment: No, it doesn't work. whatsapp is not restoring messages even when it has found backup of 1.6 GB. 0 messages restored was written. it again and again prompts to check google drive. but i dont have backup on google drive. you alll are tech enthusiast please help. or if i put my old local backup in whatsapp folder and now tap backup after installing whatsapp. will it also backup this previous files or only the new chat?

Comment: Any Solution found?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you ever solved this or not but I have the solution.

First, lets call your original device, "Device A", and your new device, "Device B".

Device A should have all your local whatsapp backup files located in your internal device storage whatsapp database folder. Those files should have dates on them for the last 7 days (ex. msgstore-2020-03-08.1.db.crypt12).  Copy one of those dated files in Device A to another location (you could place it anywhere as long as you could retrieve it on Device B later. To be safe, choose a file date at least the day before you switched phones).

Now on Device B, go to settings Backup. Make sure you have Local Backup enabled (when enabling, it might look like youre enabling Google Drive backup but youre not, just follow the steps to back up to your local drive). To confirm you have back up enabled, go to your internal storage Whatsapp database folder in Device B, check to see if there is a msgstore.db file located there. If there is then you've got backup enabled on Device B.

Now uninstall Whatsapp on Device B. (This will not delete the internal storage local backup files on Device B, it will just enable you to run a restore which only happens during device set up).

Transfer the copied file you chose on Device A to a temporary random location on Device B for future retrieval (excluding the local database folder). On Device B, rename the transferred file to "msgstore.db" removing the date and leaving the crypt12 file extension part unchanged.  When renamed, the full filename should look like this "msgstore.db.crypt12".

Now browse to Device B internal storage whatsapp database folder. Delete all files in this folder. (There should only be one since youve only backed up the new whatsapp on Device B once, but if you've been backing up for a while and only want the backup from Device A then these backup files on Device B arent needed. If you want to keep them you can always save a copy of them elsewhere. For now we'll be replacing them with the renamed backup file from Device A). Next go to the temp location where you've placed the renamed file, and move it to the now empty Device B internal storage Whatsapp Database folder. There should now only be one file in Device B's whatsapp database folder which is your renamed file.

Next go to your playstore/appstore and install whatsapp on Device B. Make sure to provide the same phone number you had once registered on Device A. Once installed and number confirmed, it should automatically prompt to restore. Click to restore. When it asks to restore from Google drive continue clicking allow, yes and restore. (This part can be confusing since youre not restoring from Google Drive but when its past this it will see that there's no google drive to restore from and will automatically detect the local backup files instead). Click allow to access internal storage files. (This will allow it to find your recently renamed restore file).

Your whatsapp should restore now with all previous contacts, messages and everything else. Hope that helps.